# List of Views add-on modules

Tags: views

Is there anywhere that I can find a list of add-on modules for the Views module?  If I search for "Views plugins" or "Views add-on", the search just picks up on "Views" and returns a million results that contain "Views".  I was hoping to find a list of things like "views_conditional", "views_or", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use google (or some other search engine if that's your thing), or drupal.org search.

On the drupal search pages you can filter by modules and by the "views" category, among other things.

For example, see [https://drupal.org/search/site/views?f[0]=&f[1]=&f[2]=im_vid_3%3A89&f[3]=drupal_core%3A103&f[4]=sm_field_project_type%3Afull&f[5]=ss_meta_type%3Amodule&solrsort=iss_project_release_usage+desc](https://drupal.org/search/site/views?f%5b0%5d=&f%5b1%5d=&f%5b2%5d=im_vid_3%3A89&f%5b3%5d=drupal_core%3A103&f%5b4%5d=sm_field_project_type%3Afull&f%5b5%5d=ss_meta_type%3Amodule&solrsort=iss_project_release_usage+desc)

Other than that there are no secret ways, just persistent searching.

Comment: I had done both.  Never noticed the Views module filter, though.  Thanks, that helps narrow things down!